# How to make element center (horizontally) with fixed position when there is min-width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following codes:

```css
div{
 position: fixed;
 border: solid 1px #aaa;
 top: 20px;
 right: 50%;
 margin-right: -20%;
 width: 40%;
 min-width: 250px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div> This element should be center (horizontally) in all screen-sizes </div>
```

`<div>` *(in the code above)* is center when its `width` is more than `250px`. But when I decrease the size of screen and `min-width: 250px;` executes, then it is not center anymore.

How can I keep it center in all-screen-sizes?

**Note:** *(legacy browser support)* crossing browsers is important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way:

```css
div{
    position: fixed;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div> This element should be center (horizontally) in all screen-sizes </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `left: 50%` and `transform: translate(-50%, 0);`

```css
div{
  position: fixed;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  top: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div> This element should be center (horizontally) at all screen-sizes </div>
```

Or you can use **JQuery**

```js
$(window).on("resize", function () {
  var half = $('div').width()/2;
  $('div').css('margin-left', -half);
}).resize();
```

```css
div{
  position: fixed;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  top: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> This element should be center (horizontally) at all screen-sizes </div>
```

Comment: This line of code `transform: translateX(-50%);` is valid on the old browsers?

Comment: Your solution is fine .. But the most of my website's users use IE8 `:)` .. So I think this isn't much proper for me .. anyway ok tnx. +1

Comment: Do you want to use JS then?

Comment: I don't know, if there is no pure-CSS approach, Then yeah, I have to use JS.

Comment: @Shafizadeh IE8 Users? Use `<table><tr>` based design instead xD!

Comment: May you please change `resize` event? Because some users open my website via cell-phone in first *(so there isn't any re-size)*

Comment: Ah ok tnx again .. If I find no better answer after a while, I will mark yours as accepted answer.

Comment: Well, What do you think about [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798774/how-to-make-element-center-horizontally-with-fixed-position-when-there-is-min/35800287#35800287) ?

Comment: I am not sure about that approach, but if its working for you that's great.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use margin:auto; property. Simply set the width of the div with percentage and set the margin to auto and it will be automatically center positioned when re-sizing the window.

if you want to keep your div fixed then you can simply use percentage in margin.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
    .fixedCenter {height:200px;
                    width:60%;
                    background-color:green;
                    position:fixed;
                    margin:10px 20%;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fixedCenter">


    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show me a fiddle? As far as I know, `margin: auto;` doesn't make center an element which has `postion: fixed;` property.

Comment: min-width does not affect the center align unless the width of the window becomes less than the min-width value. doesn't matter what approach you use the min-width will prevent centering the div in less windows sizes